# Можно ли переменной присовить значения нескольких перменных?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть куча переменных, такого типа:

```
c = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[350]/td[2]/text()')[0]
c1 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[351]/td[2]/text()')[0]
c2 = parsed_body.xpath('//html/body/table/tbody/tr[352]/td[2]/text()')[0]
```

и т.д.
Необходимо все эти переменные запихать в одну новую переменную. Возможно?

Comment: Да, в кортеж или список запихните если нужно.

Comment: очень похоже, что человек просто ещё не знает, что такое массив.

Comment: @sakhalin, вы хотите три раза одно и то же значение в переменную записать? или в примере строки все-таки должны различаться чем-то кроме имен переменных?

Comment: @insolor Извиняюсь, поправил, все значения разные.

Answer (score 0):

```
cc = [c, c1, c2]
```

подойдет? или что то другое надо?
Доставать так:

```
cc[0]   #это первый элемент - ваше 'c'
```